# How to set prototype class fields?

Tags: typescript

In vanilla JavaScript, it's easy to set up a class' prototype fields:

```js
class Bird {
  static {
    this.prototype.canFly = true;
  }
}
```

```js
new Bird().canFly // true
```

However, in TypeScript, the compiler complains that the property doesn't exist. We could mark the line with the error with `@ts-ignore` and it would work, but then we lose intellisense and type checking for this field.

Also, we can't declare the class field explicitly because then we are expected to initialize the field, which defeats the purpose of setting up the prototype.

```js
class Bird {
  canFly: boolean; // Property 'canFly' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
  static {
    this.prototype.canFly = true;
  }
}
```

Even if we `@ts-ignore` it, the field is still initialized with `undefined` just for being explicitly declared.

```js
class Bird {
  // @ts-ignore
  canFly: boolean;
  static {
    this.prototype.canFly = true;
  }
}

new Bird().canFly; // undefined
```

I also tried to "externally" declare the field with `declare` keyword, but it's also not possible:

```js
class Bird { // Duplicate identifier 'Bird'.ts(2300)
  static {
    this.prototype.canFly = true;
  }
}

declare class Bird { // Duplicate identifier 'Bird'.ts(2300)
  canFly: boolean;
}
```

Is there a TypeScript way of declaring that the field exists without having to initializing it in the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript isn't great at typing traditional `prototype` patterns.

That said, there are work arounds.

---

> Is there a TypeScript way of declaring that the field exists without having to initializing it in the instance?

Yes, with `declare`.

```
class Bird {
  declare canFly: boolean

  clipWings() {
    this.canFly = false
  }
}

Bird.prototype.canFly = true
```

Which compiles to:

```
class Bird {
    clipWings() {
        this.canFly = false;
    }
}
Bird.prototype.canFly = true;
```

And does what you expect:

```
const wildBird = new Bird()
console.log(wildBird.canFly) // true

const cagedBird = new Bird()
cagedBird.clipWings()
console.log(cagedBird.canFly) // false

// only the instance got clipped
console.log(wildBird.canFly) // true
```

`declare` is a type only construct, and tells Typescript to pretend that this exists.

So you `declare` the `canFly` property, and now don't have to prove to the compiler that the property exists.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCWAnAJtA3gKGtZBTUYiu0wYAdgGIgCeAXNAEYD2TIu5GWJI8ADgOrwyAcwgAKAJTou2AC4ALeBAB0pSjWgBeaADMwICLi4BfDKYQplvRE1m3qvXKvJVqW6LMQBXIxmBMyCFloAHd4EGQLVG0yXBC4JGRJPwCIVicQJmExMIio53VqKQB6Yo9vX39A4NJhXEjE91j4qOTa+vzQPkERcQkUwPTlTOz2hss1VxKyvQNfAbS2Yayc8PHkAqnoUvKfIA)

---

**Important note:** `declare` is not type safe, as it just pretends that a value exists there when used. This can cause major type safety issues if misused. Avoid using this in production code unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Making it a static property does not have the same effect, because the instances won't be able to override it locally. I don't intend to change the property once it is initialized, like in your example. If it was the case, I would just create a static property. The prototype value is supposed to be a default value for the class fields, just like it is with methods. This is not bizarre at all to me, it's exactly how the prototype chain was designed to work.

Comment: If one individual bird loses its ability to fly `bird1.canFly = false`, other birds should remain able to fly `bird2.canFly === true`. They are unrelated instances.

Comment: If all you want is a default value, then why not just `class Bird { canFly = true }`? Manual edits to the prototype from a `class` is unconventional. You typically don't mix classes declared with the `class` keyword with prototypical inheritance via the `prototype` property.

Comment: Because there is no need to replicate the same values into all instances of the class. It might not make much of a diffecence in most cases, but it's particularly significant in applications that deal with a large amount of objects that have a large amount of properties. It's much quicker to build an object that has few properties and just point to the prototype for the rest, than having to initialize all fields for every instance.

Comment: I see your point, and have updated my answer now that I understand what you are after better.